# What's the music in the end of Star Trek: Enterprise S03E18?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, music-identification

There is a song (or tune) at the end of *Enterprise* season 3 episode 18 (about 4 minutes from the end and playing almost non stop until the end). It's the song that's playing when the reptilians attack the ship and cause massive damage.

It has no lyrics and I've been trying to find it, with little success.

Does anyone know what it is? Was it made just for Enterprise or is it an existing tune?. It's been bugging me for years (every time I re-watch it). I was hoping it was in the credits but Netflix doesn't let me watch them without trying to switch to the next episode.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l6DhCtvZvI is this the scene you mean?

Comment: yes, i will add that to the question thanks

Comment: Pretty sure it's just original scoring to underline threes tension of the battle/finale. Compare with the _Die Is Cast_ from DS9 https://youtu.be/5vSp9CLyImA

Comment: @HorusKol It's original scoring but I think Matt's looking for a track title or listing. Which I haven't managed to find, but I do know the OST for that episode hasn't been released. If the same music shows up in another episode, that might help.

Answer (score 3):

It is [**"End Game"** by **Jay Chattaway** (YouTube link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Iq9v3I--OQ)

Found in [STAR TREK COLLECTION - THE FINAL FRONTIER (4CD), CD No:   LLLCD-1591](https://arksquare.net/detail.php?cdno=LLLCD-1591)

Release Date: 2022/04/05

[Episode itself (battle scene)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhLqjOLmhV4)

One more link to the soundtrack: [soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/christian-s-davila/ent-azati-prime-endgame)

[image]